# Android Facebook SDK 3.x Loggin issue

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-3.0

The requirement of my app is simple, all i want to do is to login from user and request the logged in user's First and last name, Gender and Email ID, tried simple login code from the Facebook getting started tutorial and couple of other codes as well, some works fine without the Facebook apps installed while others the opposite,

If someone could just refer me to a good piece of login code for Facebook with Email and gender permissions

Comment: The most likely cause of your login NOT working with the Facebook app installed is you didn't add (or didn't add the correct) key hashes in your app settings. Make sure you follow every step in the Getting Started guide. Also, if you post some output from logcat showing failures or exceptions, it makes it easier to help diagnose the issue.

Comment: My key hashes are correct because it works on some devices and works perfectly fine without the Facebook app installed, i would appreciate if some could just post the Code snippet of working login code :(

Comment: If your app works without the Facebook app installed, it's even more evidence that it's the key hashes, because key hashes are ONLY used when the Facebook app is present (and can do SSO).